# Windows XP UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME error (Eee PC)

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot, partitioning, console

A few days ago the laptop started working slowly and I shut it down forcefully which caused a boot error (UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME), I managed to get into the recovery console on a USB Windows XP and the 'dir' command isn't working saying "An error occured during directory enumeration".

I first got an Ubuntu iso and made the USB drive bootable, booted into Ubuntu and the partitions are ok except that I can't mount the partition where Windows XP was installed. Then I booted into the Windows XP USB, entered Recovery Console, I can get into 4 partitions, one of them is the second Data partition I have on the laptop, the second one I can get into is the USB partition, I think I have a third EFI partition or something on the laptop and I am not sure which is the Windows partition C: or F: .

C: partition takes a while to show me the error after I execute 'dir' command.

**Does it matter on which partition I execute 'chkdsk /r'?** and **Is there a way to see partitions and partition size from Recovery Console?** (So I can know which is the Windows partition)

Answer (score 0):

if you are in the windows console environment (cmd) try "diskpart".
to get the disk partition layout do the following:

- diskpart
- list disk (this will give you a list of disks you need to remember the disk number for later)
- select disk # (eg "select disk 0" => here put the number you got in the step before)
- list partition

in your case it is generaly a good idea to run the chkdsk command on all the partitions.

Comment: I did diskpart and it shows me an interface of the partitions, which is good because F: is only 31 MB large and C: is way bigger, so C: is the Windows partition. Also can 'chkdsk /r" corrupt files or data on the partition or not?

Comment: well the answer is not that clear. chkdsk only removes the ramains of the structure which is corrupt. the (meta-)data which is corrupt will be removed and the rest will not be touched. a backup is a good idea. but in your situation my *GUESS* is that the meta-data in the file-system (basically a complaint that the os has not been shut down cleanly => the partrtition has not been unmounted cleanly) that is prohibiting you from booting. (meta-data will be regenerated in the process.)

Comment: Yes, that's why I can't also mount it on Ubuntu, I couldn't mount it on Ubuntu on another computer too because Windows crashed and didn't boot back into Windows. Then I had to boot back into Windows and shut it down correctly. Ok I'm gonna execute 'chkdsk /r' on C: now.

Comment: Ok I did 'chksdk /r' it stopped at 50% and said there is an unrecoverable error. Now I get a 'PROCESS1_INITALIZATION_FAILED' error (0x0000006B) at boot. What should I do? I'll try 'chkdsk /r' again. If it doesn't work what other commands should I try?

Comment: It seems it recognized in the recovery console that there is a Windows installation this time. I also found this https://neosmart.net/wiki/0x0000006b/ and I can use 'dir' command. ntdll.dll seems to be missing from system32.